# Django REST Updateview with PUT POST

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Within a *listview*, with many objects, I want to change their value live by javascript, then save them by a POST/PUT http request to the object *updateview*, searching I've found that it maybe possible with Django REST framework.

I've read the Django REST framework 
[manual reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin)

but didn't understand how to set up the UpdateView call:

**model.py**

```
class presetrows(models.Model):
    progressivo = models.ForeignKey(preset)
    value = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class RighePresetListView(ListView):
    queryset = presetrows.objects.filter(stato=True)

class RighePresetUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = presetrows
    exclude=()
```

but where should I add the update(request, *args, **kwargs) from django REST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really needs to define `update(request, *args, **kwargs)` in DRF views. For update api you can use this

```
class RighePresetUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = 'your serializer'
    queryset = presetrows.objects.filter(stato=True)
```

Provides put and patch method handlers implicitly.