# Update/put request in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django REST Framework and trying it for a new project I am working on. So based upon the official tutorial , I am trying to create several get/post/put requests, but with put request I am getting the following error:

> Expected view ExampleUpdateView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

#### Here are my necessary files:

**`models.py`**

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    foo_field = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    bar_field = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_updated_on = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'example_db'
        unique_together = (('foo_field', 'bar_field'),)
```

**`serializers.py`**

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ('foo_field', 'bar_field', 'last_updated_by', 'last_updated_on')
```

**`urls.py`**

```
url(r'^get_example/$', views.ExampleCreateView.as_view()),
url(r'^update_example/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ExampleUpdateView.as_view()),
```

**`views.py`**

```
class ExampleCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()

class ExampleUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
```

I think the problem I might have is that I have a composite key. I tried other generic views (CreateAPIView & ListAPIView) and they work absolutely fine. Do I need to update the `def_update` method? Do I need to change anything in `serializers.py`?

This is an existing JSON object that I got from my GET request and was trying to update:

```
{
    "foo_field": "john",
    "bar_field": "doe",
    "last_updated_by": "batman",
    "last_updated_on": "2017-02-09"
}
```

I looked at the following duplicates but none of these solution seems to work for me:

[Django Rest Framework: Unclear error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400362/django-rest-framework-unclear-error-message/44402905#44402905)

[Django REST Updateview with PUT POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014664/django-rest-updateview-with-put-post/32015081#32015081)

[How do I use an UpdateView to update a Django Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271757/how-do-i-use-an-updateview-to-update-a-django-model)

Comment: Your `urls.py` is a clear anti-pattern. That's NOT REST! You don't put the verb into the URL! The HTTP request methods should map to CRUD: POST - CREATE; GET - RETRIEVE; PUT - UPDATE; DELETE - DELETE.

Comment: You have set `foo_field` as primary key, so you don't use composite key. Django doesn't support composite keys. What you have is `unique_together` and that is `UNIQUE KEY`, not a composite key. By the way it is a bad practice to use strings as primary keys.

Comment: What is the real reason you need to use `CreateAPIView` and `UpdateAPIView`? Why not `ListCreateAPIView` and `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`? Or why not just going straight forward to viewsets? What are your particular requirements?

Comment: CreateAPIView and UpdateAPIView were just examples. I tried with RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView but the put request in the latter still gives me the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I'll refactor your code and present the code examples. Afterwards I'll explain the changes.

**`models.py`**

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    foo_field = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    # rest ...
```

You have set `foo_field` as primary key. It is a bad practice to use strings (`VARCHAR`) as primary key. It is highly recommended to use [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). This will be accomplished automatically by Django. It adds a field `id` as primary key.

The `serializers.py` will now work as it is. No changes are needed. Also the `views.py` should work without changes. However I'll cover the option with `foo_field` as primary key.

**`views.py`**

```
class ExampleUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    # rest ...
    lookup_field = `foo_field`
```

You could also leave this out, but it is important to make some changes in your `urls.py`.

**`urls.py`**

```
url(r'^examples/$', views.ExampleCreateView.as_view()),
url(r'^examples/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ExampleUpdateView.as_view()),
```

In order for a web services to be ReSTful, they have to comply with the REST principles. One of the most important rules is that we shouldn't use a verb in the URL for describing the action. Another convention is that the resource name is used in plural to describe the collection and an identifier is used to access single resource.

Your resource is called **example**, therefore we use **examples** as collection name. Verbs like get or update have no place in the URL. The HTTP method is responsible for the proper action.

If you'd like to use `foo_field` as primary key, then you have to change the url for the update view:

```
url(r'^examples/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$',views.ExampleUpdateView.as_view()),
```

This is because your `foo_field` is a `CharField` (or string), so the arguments passed to it should match any alphanumeric character (`\w`) and the hyphen (`-`).
You can use `foo_field` as named group in your url regex instead of `pk` if you wish. Pay attention that you adapt that in your view, setting the correct values for `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg`.

Again I'll strongly recommend to use surrogate keys and leave Django to accomplish this task.

Now you can understand why `ListAPIView` and `CreateAPIView` worked. They don't require an argument passed to the url and were properly called.
Your `UpdateAPIView` couldn't work because the matching url was accepting only digits and didn't match your primary key `foo_field`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I now understand why 
    ListAPIView and     ListAPIView worked but     UpdateAPIView did not. Unfortunately much as I would like to use surrogate key(Django's Autofield in this case), it is not in my hand to choose that(my technical lead said a hard no). I don't have control over the database(using inspectdb right now).  I **have** to use the composite key and that too with VARCHAR.

Comment: @VasuGaur In that case use `foo_field` as primary key and take care that you set `lookup_field` in the view. Use the second example for the url, to match any alphanumeric character, or whatever your requirements are.

Answer (score 4):

Use `update()` wiht your `UpdateAPIView`.

```
class ExampleUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
        queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

        def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = self.get_object()
            instance.foo_field = request.data.get("foo_field")
            instance.bar_field = request.data.get("bar_field")
            instance.last_updated_by = request.data.get("last_updated_by")
            instance.last_updated_on = request.data.get("last_updated_on")
            instance.save()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_update(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```